# Matching First and Last Name on two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am trying to match the first name varchar (50) and last name varchar(50) from table A to the first name varchar(50) and last name varchar(50) on table B. The issue is that both table contain a lot of shortened first names like the name Andrew in table A and there might be a matching record with the last name but the first name is Andy so it comes up as not a match. Is there anyway to get around this in SQL. The shortened names is a vice verse problem meaning that both Table A and Table B have some shortened names.

Here are some more examples:

[image]

This is my current code.

```
Select *
FROM TableA p
JOIN TableB e ON e.CompanyNumber = 1 and e.LastName like '%' + rtrim(ltrim(p.lastname)) + '%' 
     and e.FirstName like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(p.firstname)) + '%'
```

NOTE: This is the only way to match the tables together.

Comment: So Andy and Andrew should match? as well as Bill and William?

Comment: Yes, So "Andy Johnson" in Table A should match "Andrew Johnson" in Table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you use a 3rd Table to hold you Long/Short Names as so.

```
CREATE TABLE TableNames
    ([Id] int, [OfficialName] varchar(7), [Alias] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO TableNames
    ([Id], [OfficialName], [Alias])
VALUES
    (1, 'Andrew', 'Andy'),
    (2, 'Andrew', 'Andrew'),
    (3, 'William', 'Bill'),
    (4, 'William', 'William'),
    (5, 'David', 'Dave'),
    (6, 'David', 'David')
```

The following query should give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TableA.Id AS T1_Id
        ,CompanyId AS T1_CompanyId
        ,FirstName AS T1_FirstName
        ,LastName AS T1_LastName
        ,TableNames.OfficialName AS OfficialName
    FROM tableA
    INNER JOIN tableNames ON TableA.FirstName = TableNames.Alias
    ) T1
    ,(
        SELECT tableB.Id AS T2_Id
            ,CompanyId AS T2_CompanyId
            ,FirstName AS T2_FirstName
            ,LastName AS T2_LastName
            ,TableNames.OfficialName AS OfficialName
        FROM tableB
        INNER JOIN tableNames ON TableB.FirstName = TableNames.Alias
        ) T2
WHERE T1.T1_CompanyId = T2.T2_CompanyId
    AND T1.OfficialName = T2.OfficialName
    AND T1.T1_LastName = T2.T2_LastName
```

I set up my solution sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64514/2

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Create a third table that associates Long-form and short-form names.

For examle:

```
Long Form    Short Form
Andrew       Andy
Andrew       Drew
David        Dave
William      Will
William      Bill
William      Billy
William      Willy
```

Comment: Ya, I was thinking that as well. Do you happen to know of a source that already has a table made so I don't have to create my own?

Comment: link link has some but not all... https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1005091900001

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
<br>FROM TableA pJOIN TableB e 
<br>ON e.CompanyNumber = 1 
<br>and e.LastName like '%' + rtrim(ltrim(p.lastname)) + '%' 
     <br>OR 
<br>e.FirstName like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(p.firstname)) + '%'
```

Now this depends how you determine it is match,
example:

```
TableA:
--------
Rownum  FristName    LastName
1        Andy        Smith
2        Andy        Mathew

TableB:
--------
Rownum  FristName    LastName
1        Logan       Andy
2        Mathew      Andy
```

Now will you consider first record from both the tables as a match

What about the second record in both the tables?

Basing on this we can even change the query

Comment: The first row is not a match because "Andy Smith" is not the same person as "Logan Andy". The last names need to match no matter what. The second record is not a match either.